# How Connection Disconnects in HTTP?

Tags: http, tcp

As we all know that the HTTP is stateless protocol, **means it disconnects the connection after the end of every transaction.**

But that's not enough for me to understand it. What makes me confuse that, ***Is the TCP connection also ends?***

As HTTP is a TCP network protocol, so it talks to other nodes through the TCP pipe. So Is the `stateless` means that the `TCP connection also ends`? 
So, it will make another TCP connection by using another TCP 3 way-handshake?

Answer (score 0):

What makes the protocol stateless is that the server is not required to track state over multiple requests, not that it cannot do so if it wants to. This simplifies the contract between client and server, and in many cases minimizes the amount of data that needs to be transferred.and the Internet is a stateless development environment" is often used. This simply means that **the HTTP that is the backbone of the Web is unable to retain a memory of the identity of each client that connects to a Web site and therefore treats each request for a Web page as a unique and independent connection,** with no relationship whatsoever to the connections that preceded it.

Comment: No, that is different from my question.

Comment: Please see the confusing part of the question. I highlighted the part.

Answer (score 0):

> As we all know that the HTTP is stateless protocol, means it disconnects the connection after the end of every transaction.

No, we don't all know that it means that at all: no, it *doesn't* mean that at all; and no, it doesn't do that at all.

> What makes me confuse that, Is the TCP connection also ends?

The TCP connection ends when the HTTP connection ends.

> As HTTP is a TCP network protocol, so it talks to other nodes through the TCP pipe.

Correct.

> So Is the stateless means that the TCP connection also ends?

No. The HTTP and TCP connections can be persistent, and they are by default from HTTP 1.1 (previously via the so-called KEEPALIVE feature). This has nothing to do with statelessness.

> So, it will make another TCP connection by using another TCP 3 way-handshake?

Yes, whenever required, but that isn't as often as you seem to think. You are conflating two different aspects of HTTP.

Comment: I really don't know why you do not agree on HTTP is stateless?

Comment: And you said TCP connection ends when the HTTP connection ends. So it means before HTTP 1.1 when the http connection ends then it automatically tcp connection also ends, now to connect again to the server client will fire up the TCP connection to occur the HTTP connection?

Comment: I do *not* 'disagree on HTTP [being] stateless'. I disagree that it has the implication you are relying on, specifically your words 'as we all know ... means ...'. Your second comment merely repeats your original question, which I have already answered.

Comment: It wouldn't be bad to add how HTTP2 changes this somewhat; the expectation will be that there is a single TCP connection over which all HTTP transactions are performed rather than multiple TCP streams.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Frankly I think it would only add to the confusion here, which is between 'stateless' and 'connection'.

Comment: @ejp fair enough.

Comment: In your answer on the second line you highlighted ` Is the TCP connection also ends?` Please add Yes OR  No in your answer, So it will easy to understand it. :)

Comment: @UtkarshAgrawal 'The TCP connection ends when the HTTP connection ends' is already perfectly clear as far as I am concerned. It is in fact clearer than 'yes' or 'no' as a response to the rather poorly expressed quote it addresses. I am trying to clear up confusions here, not add to them.